# Exclude selected values and NAs from colSums R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a small R dataframe which can be reproduced from code below

```
structure(list(Replicate_No = 1:6, `1` = c(60.7, 60.83, 60.12, 
60.66, 60.51, 60.53), `2` = c(60.74, 60.9, 60.41, 60.7, 60.62, 
60.71), `3` = c(60.71, 60.65, 60.79, 60.75, 60.82, 60.82), `4` = c(60.7, 
60.7, 60.7, 60.6, 60.8, 61), `6` = c(60.704, 60.496, 60.742, 
60.831, 60.955, 60.698), `7` = c(60.74, 61.29, 60.68, 60.55, 
61.26, 60.46), `8` = c(60.89, 61.21, 61.04, 61.28, 61.05, 61.15
), `9` = c(60.67, 60.47, 60.74, 60.96, 60.58, 60.79)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

value 60.1 in the 2nd column is an outlier determined from grubs test. I have assigned the outlier value to grb.out. I want to do a column count but exclude that value from being counted.  I initially converted the outlier value to NA and have the following code which gave me the desired output.

```
df.count <- colSums(!is.na(df[, 2:length(df)]))
```

my question is how can I use colSums or similar another function to not count the outlier value(s) as well as ignoring NA. I would like to ignore NAs as well as at times I will have NA values but for different reasons.

As a starting point have tried

```
df.count <- colSums(!= grb.out(df[, 2:length(df)]))
df.count <- colSums(!= 60.1 (df[, 2:length(df)]))
```

I get an error saying "unexpected "!=" in df.count ...

Any advice would be great, tips or direction would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following with `sapply` :

```
df.count <-  sapply(round(df[-1], 1) function(x) 
                     sum(!(x %in% grb.out | is.na(x))))
```

Or with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
round(df, 1) %>% summarise(across(-1, ~sum(!(. %in% grb.out | is.na(.)))))
```

Comment: thanks, your first solution works. I have tried the second solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that `grb.out` is a `data.frame` of the same dimensions as your `df`. Try this:

```
df.count <- colSums(df[, 2:length(df)] != grb.out)
df.count <- colSums(df[, 2:length(df)] != 60.1)
```

If `grb.out` is a function that takes a `data.frame` as its first argument, then

```
df.count <- colSums(df[, 2:length(df)] != grb.out(df[, 2:length(df)]))
```

Comment: thanks, your first two solutions answer part of my question.  I would like to combine NA into the code as well.  In this example grb.out is a singular value that = 60.1. I might have occurrences where I have multiple outlier values that need to be considered which I would probably store as a vector